# How do I import Motionbuilder animation into my game?

Tags: java, 3d, models

I have an animation sequence for a 3D model built in Autodesk Motionbuilder. How would import the data for the sequence into my java game for my model? Is there any tutorial on how to accomplish this? I already have my 3D model loaded into the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every game company has its own trick and method. The way I think you should do it is to export each frame and then load each frame in order to your java application. This process is called animation.